# Probability of A * B = 0

Tags: probability

Given an expression:

> E = A * B

We are to find P(E = 0), when:
 P(A) = p<sub>1</sub> , P(B) = p<sub>2</sub>

What I did was tried for some cases like:

**Case 1:** For,P(A=0) = 0.5 & P(B=0) = 0.5 , P(E=0) = 0.75 . Since there are four possibilities 0*B, A*0, 0*0 , A*B and only 3 are 0, hence 3/4.

**Case 2:** When P(A=0) = P(B=0) = 1, P(E=0)=1 ; since the product is always 0

If I solve it like

> P(E) = p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub> + p<sub>1</sub>(1-p<sub>2</sub>) + (1-p<sub>1</sub>)p<sub>2</sub>

Is it correct?
If not, how should I solve it?

Comment: Yes but it might have been simpler to consider the complement i.e. \begin{align}\mathbb{P}(A\cdot B=0)&=1-\mathbb{P}(A\cdot B\ne0)\\&=1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\\\end{align}

Comment: Another way would be $P(A*B=0) = P(A=0 \text{ or }B=0) = P(A=0) + P(B=0) - P(A=0 \text{ and } B=0)$.

Comment: okay..thanks for the help!